# Error when trying to connect to oracle DB from selenium

Tags: oracle, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to connect to a oracle db from Selenium using jdbc and I'm getting the following message:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

I'm able to connect to this db from pl/sql successfully but from jdbc I'm getting this error. Below is the code. Anyone could help me here?

```
    @Test
    public void test11 () {

    String server = "host";
    String port = "1521";
    String database = "db";
    String user = "user";
    String pwd = "pw";

    try {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + server + ":" + port + "/" + database;

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

LISTENER.ORA:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = "net_service_name")
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1)
        (SID_NAME = "net_service_name")
    )
    (SID_DESC = 
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = "service_name")
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1)
        (SID_NAME = "service_name")
    )
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = "host")(PORT = 1521))
        )
    )
)
```

TNSNAMES.ORA:

```
"net_service_name"=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = "host")(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = "service_name")
    )
  )
```

Comment: Does your oracle listener have a Service called "db"? Make sure that string is correct or that the db actually exists on that machine.

Comment: You mean the GLOBAL_DBNAME? If so, yes, it does. I added the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora to the question, do u think those are correct?

Comment: it's not so much what your listener.ora file SAYS, it's what your listener THINKS, try running lsnrctl status at a bash prompt, and see if your "db" is listed

Comment: I'm getting the message below when I try that:
SQL> lsnrctl status
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "lsnrctl st..." - rest of line ignored.

Comment: lsnrctl is a program like sqlplus is a program

Comment: C:\>lsnrctl status    >>>>   lsnrctl' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Comment: you do this on the database server, not on your client

Comment: I don't think I have access to the server

Answer (score 0):

I think you incorrect used

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + server + ":" + port + "/" + database;
```

: instead /

Try with your params

```
public static void conn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orclpdb", "HR", "HR"); 
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from dual");  
    while(rs.next())  
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));  
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: With : instead of / I get this: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: "service_name" instead database(db) in "/" + database;

Comment: Excellent, it worked now! Thank you very much @Rustam

Comment: @Tester, confirm, please, my answer as rigth